# VirtualBox sharing a folder

Tags: virtualbox, shared-folders

I had to share a folder on my virtual machine, Windows XP running on VirtualBox installed on Windows 7. How do I do that?

I learnt about a command, "net use...", but that didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 7 running in VirtualBox cannot see shared folders](https://superuser.com/questions/72806/windows-7-running-in-virtualbox-cannot-see-shared-folders)

Answer (score 2):

Install [Guest Additions](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html).

Comment: hey i found it...got it...