# how do I share a folder beetwen Linux running Android on Virtual box?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, android, shared-folders

I'm running Android (without installing it) through VirtualBox under Ubuntu. I already added a folder of my Ubuntu system, in the shared folder settings in VirtualBox.

Now the question is: how do I access this folder from inside the virtualized Android?
where is it?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://superuser.com/questions/225281/virtualbox-sharing-a-folder) will useful for you. Good question +.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure how this would work by default, as Android really wasn't built to access network shares. I'd recommend downloading a file explorer app like ES file explorer or Astro (my favorite, both are free and work well though) on the android VM. These have the ability to access network shares on your local network. If it doesn't work through the share solution in VirtualBox, then you can just share it from your desktop and point the browser to the network share name, something like \your_pcs_name\sharefolder.

Comment: This is the right way to do it, though I prefer File Expert as the app to browse the network shares: https://market.android.com/details?id=xcxin.filexpert